# Why Elasticsearch uses PUT instead of POST for creating index?

Tags: elasticsearch

As far as I know, `POST` is usually used for changing the state of the server, and `PUT` usually for updating the information. If I am creating a new index, should it not be POST instead of PUT? `PUT` does make sense when creating a document as it changes the state of data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between POST and PUT in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-put-in-http)

Comment: @Joel umm.. OK.

Comment: Yeah well... Not sure what other answer you expect. There are reasons for using PUT over POST, whiich - when you boil it down, is what you are asking for. Also, the answer in the post I linked, provides a great illustration of why to use PUT in this very scenario. Hence, it answers your question.. If you aren't satisfied with the answer. **go find it** https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch

Comment: @Joel For docs creation, they use `POST` and for update `PUT`?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement

> As far as I know, POST is usually used for changing the state of the server, and PUT usually for updating the information.

does conform to the conventional [HTTP vs CRUD semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Semantics_of_HTTP_methods):

| HTTP method | CRUD equivalent | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **POST** | Create | Let the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request. |
| **PUT** | Update | Set the target resource’s state to the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request. |

However, the [PUT spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) *also* stipulates that:

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource **be
> created** or replaced with the state defined by the representation
> enclosed in the request message payload

As such, PUT can (and is) used in Elasticsearch to both [**create**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html) an index AND **update** its
[[settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html) and [mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html)].

---

Also, keep in mind that it's rarely just a matter of strict adherence to the semantics. One of the creators of ES [put it this way](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/when-to-use-put-versus-post/68550/3?u=joesorocin):

> > It's all about REST semantics.
>
> And our understanding of the semantics at the time when we made the APIs. And backwards compatibility constraints. And whatever "feels" natural to the person who implemented the API.
>
> Where it makes a lot of sense Elasticsearch maps the HTTP verbs to
> useful things. But when it doesn't make a ton of sense we just go with
> whatever verb feels good rather than trying to be super strict about
> REST. Also, we don't do linked data, instead relying on you to build
> links from context. I'm told that is particularly non-REST. But it is
> what we do.